# What's the probability of getting 2 jokers on 5 hands of cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assuming that the shuffled deck of cards contains 54 cards (including the 2 Jokers), what is the probability of getting the two Jokers if I was handed 5 card hand?

What I've tried:

Since 5 hand cards can be imagined by simulating the probability of having a card on each hand one-by-one, I've tried the following simulations:

I imagined that the probability of having a Joker on the first card on my hand is 2/54.

Assuming that the first card on the hand contains a Joker, there is a 1/53 chance for the next card to have Joker.

Assuming that the second card on the hand contains the other Joker, the rest of the 3 cards doesn't matter anymore, so they all contains a 52/52 probability for each.

I think the formula goes as follows: 5 * ((2/54) (1/53) (52/52) (52/52) (52/52)) = 5/1431

I am not quite sure if this is the right answer or method, so I thought about consulting this website. Thanks alot!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I had updated my post to include the method I had tried, although I'm very unsure whether it's the correct method. Apologies if the post seemed lazy before the edit, It's my first time posting here.

Comment: The formal name for this distribution is the [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: The probability you found in your attempt of $\frac{2}{54}\times\frac{1}{53}$ is the probability that when pulling five cards in sequence that very specifically the first and the second cards were jokers.  This does not cover the cases of it being the first and third cards in the hand, or the first and fourth cards in the hand, or the second and fifth cards in the hand etc...  You multiplied your result by five, but that is not a good enough fix for this.  There are more than five places that the jokers could *collectively* be.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for this follows from the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  Loosely phrased, if you have a bag with $N$ balls in total, $K$ of which are red and the remaining $N-K$ of which are white... when pulling $n$ balls without replacement the probability that $k$ of them are red will be:

$$\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

Here, the jokers play the role of the "red balls", while all the non-jokers play the role of the white balls, and we pull five cards.  That is, $N=54, K=2,n=5,k=2$

The probability that you pulled both jokers will be:

$$\dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{54-2}{5-2}}{\binom{54}{5}} = \dfrac{\binom{52}{3}}{\binom{54}{5}} = \dfrac{10}{1431}$$

Note how this differs from @user253963's incorrect answer below, that they left out the crucial $\binom{52}{3}$ corresponding to how many ways you could have picked the non-jokers in the hand.

Now... your attempted answer was good however it missed a major point.  The calculation of $\dfrac{2}{54}\times\dfrac{1}{53}$ was a good one which corresponds to the probability that exactly the first and the second cards if the cards were pulled in sequence were the jokers.  You attempted to correct this calculation by multiplying by $5$, however this was not correct to do.

Instead of multiplying by five, you needed to multiply by the number of ways in which the jokers could have *collectively* been positioned within the hand taking both jokers into account at the same time.  There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways that you could have placed the two jokers within the ordering of the hand.

This gives an answer of $$\dfrac{2}{54}\times\dfrac{1}{53}\times \binom{5}{2} = \dfrac{10}{1431}$$

This of course equals the same answer as before.  I would still prefer to think of the answer in the first way since it generalizes more nicely to other problems.  This second answer worked here mostly because it happened to be *all* jokers that were appearing in our hand.  If you repeated the problem with asking about getting exactly two queens, it won't go exactly the same way with the second approach (*as it won't be multiplying by $\frac{52}{52}$ and multiplying by $\frac{51}{51}$ and such afterwards*).